# How to save DataGrid data to CSV file without enumerating the query result again?

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, export-to-csv

I am using this command to get data from my query:

```
private void loadData()
    {
        numRows = 0;

        try
        {
            data = gpso.gpEntitiesObject.ExecuteStoreQuery<My_Class>(sql);

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
            dataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
            numRows = dataGrid.Items.Count;
            numRowsTB.Text = "Number of rows: " + numRows;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            statusBarTB.Text = "exception: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Although this works and I see the data in my DataGrid, I am not able to save the data to a CSV file since I am trying to reenumerate the query result again, which is not allowed.

What would be the right way to get the data and save it to CSV?
Should I use the DataGrid API to scroll trough the rows and get the data in a foreach() loop?

Here is my CSV function:

```
    public static string exportToCSV(IEnumerable<My_Class> data, string separator)
    {
        string ishod = "";
        string csvRed = "";

        ishod += "Key1" + separator + "Key2" + separator;
        ishod += "Key3" + separator + "Key4" + separator;

        ishod += "\n";

        foreach (My_Class item in data)
        {
            csvRed += item.Key1+ separator + item.Key2+ separator;
            csvRed += item.Key3+ separator + item.Key4+ separator;

            csvRed += "\n";

            ishod += csvRed;

            csvRed = "";
        }

        return ishod;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps `dataGrid.ItemsSource = data.ToList();`

Comment: @Clemens hmm, tried to use ToList<My_Class>() but I get the same error. The problem might be that I am going trough the rows again in the exportCSV() function. Hmm, there must be a better way.

Comment: Of course with `foreach (My_Class item in dataGrid.ItemsSource)`. Or assign `data.ToList()` to another field.

Comment: @Clemens yes, thanks. I created new variable IEnumerable dataList = data.ToList<My_Class>(); I now set to dataGrid.ItemSource = dataList and sent it to my csv export function. It works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Clemens advice. I used

```
IEnumerable dataList = data.ToList<My_Class>(); 
dataGrid.ItemSource = dataList;
```

I then called

```
exportToCSV(dataList, "\t");
```

with dataList as parameter and it worked!